# Get Post ID of post you're currently editing in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm attempting to get the ID of the post I am editing in functions.php for the purpose of dynamically rewriting a custom post type slug.

This is what I'm working with so far.

```
function change_post_type_slug( $args, $post_type ) {

  if ( 'custom_post' == $post_type ) {

    global $post;
    $location = get_field('custom_field', $post->ID);
    $args['rewrite']['slug'] = $location;

  }

  return $args;

}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'change_post_type_slug', 10, 2 );
```

I am not sure if the hook `register_post_type_args` is firing before I am able to get the ID, or if this is even the best way to go about what I am trying to accomplish. Can't find much out there on the subject.

I was able to get it to work with the following:

```
function change_post_type_slug( $args, $post_type ) {

  if ( 'lead_page' == $post_type ) {

    $post_id = $_GET['post'];
    $location = get_field('leadpage_location', $post_id);
    $args['rewrite']['slug'] = $location->post_name;

  }

  return $args;

}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'change_post_type_slug', 10, 2 );
```

However it resulted in a notice on the front-end:
`Notice: Undefined index: post in /path/to/wordpress/functions.php on line 623`

Line 623 is `$post_id = $_GET['post'];`

Comment: Try this for your `if` statement: `if ( 'lead_page' === $post_type && is_admin() )` This will ensure it only fires on the admin side and not on the front end. You could also pair it with finding out if you're on the actual edit screen: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125692/how-to-know-if-admin-is-in-edit-page-or-post

Comment: That's a great addition.

Comment: If that works, let me know and I'll put it as an answer

Comment: It still unfortunately displays the notice in admin when not editing that particular post type.

Comment: yeah, you'll have to combine it with the link I added.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Try this:

```php
function change_post_types_slug( $args, $post_type ) {

   if ( 'your-custom_post' === $post_type ) {
        // Check and get the custom post ID 
        $id = isset($_GET[ 'post' ]) ? $_GET[ 'post' ] : '' ;
        // $location = get_field('leadpage_location', $id);
        $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'new-slug-here';
   }

   return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'change_post_types_slug', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: admin_head is an action not a filter use: add_action('admin_head', 'change_post_type_slug');. However this is not the correct way of doing this, you should use the updated_postmeta hook.

Comment: sorry my bad `register_post_type_args` is the right hook for this. I've updated the answer and tested it and it seems to work but i couldn't test `get_field` because I don't have ACF.

Comment: This works (sort of) and it's exactly what I have in the second box, and I am getting that Notice I mentioned above on every page that isn't the post type (while editing).

Comment: I don't have that Notice? I'm on debug mode btw. what wp version are you using? I'm using v5.1.

Comment: Also 5.1 - I get the notice with debug enabled and viewing any page on the frontend.

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: post in /var/www/html/path/to/wordpress/functions.php on line 612`

Line 612 being $id = $_GET[ 'post' ];

Comment: Hmm, try to check if there is post ID. `$id = isset($_GET[ 'post' ]) ? $_GET[ 'post' ] : '' ;`

Comment: That takes care of that notice :) However, when I change from a static slug to the dynamic slug with ACF, It's now giving a new error.

Comment: Easier to use pastebin at this point: https://pastebin.com/ivWi1d1g

Aside from this notice it's working great.

Comment: Wait. `get_field` returns `true` or `false` i guess `the_field` is what you need.

Comment: `get_field()` returns a value. The field "leadpage_location" is set to a post object.
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: I see.. check **Using conditional statements** [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/): get_field returns false if (value == “” || value == null || value == false). also see [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/)

Comment: So the reason it's giving the new notice is because if you're not editing that post type, then $id becomes nothing, and I am using $id to call the field.

Comment: Yes, i guess .. `$post_id` parameter is (Optional) though and if not present the default value will return the current post you're editing.

Comment: That is true - but since this is all being declared in the functions.php file - it wouldn't know what post to reference. I'm honestly re-thinking if this is even going to be possible. I might try to find another way. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`updated_postmeta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/updated_postmeta/) hook for this, as its run every time you update your custom fields.

Then you can update your post data with [`wp_update_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/) function.

```php
add_action( 'updated_postmeta', function( $meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value ) {

    if ( 'location' === $meta_key ) {
        wp_update_post([
            'ID' => $object_id,
            'post_name' => $meta_value,
        ]);
    }

}, 10, 4 );
```

Comment: I don't believe you can rewrite a custom post type slug with `wp_update_post()`

Comment: Yes, I am not able to get it to work. By slug I am referring to domain.com/SLUG/pagetitle. Wordpress custom post types use the post type as the slug by default unless defined otherwise when registering the post type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
function change_post_type_slug( $args, $post_type ) {

  if ( 'lead_page' === $post_type && is_admin() && $_GET['action'] === 'edit' ) {

    $post_id = $_GET['post'];
    $location = get_field('leadpage_location', $post_id);
    $args['rewrite']['slug'] = $location->post_name;

  }

  return $args;

}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'change_post_type_slug', 10, 2 );
```

It adds two more conditionals, to check if you're on the admin screen and to check of there is a `GET` parameter of `edit`. Probably overkill to do `is_admin()` as well, but now you're super safe.